# android icon error - not seeing folder?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-icons

I created the folders:

```
app_name/res/drawable-hdpi
app_name/res/drawable-mdpi
app_name/res/drawable-ldpi
```

I put icons 72x72 in hdpi, 48x48 in mdpi, and 36x36 in ldpi.  I named the png icons: icon.png

I compiled and ran it and the icons didn't change.  So then I went to `AndroidManifest.xml` and changed the icon parameter:

```
<application
        android:icon="@drawable-ldpi/icon"
...
```

However I get this error:

> Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'icon' with value '@drawable-ldpi/icon'). AndroidManifest.xml

Any tips?

Comment: You may need to add res.srcDirs to you sourceSets > main in your build.gradle file. See solution here - http://stackoverflow.com/a/17097436/857681 . I was having the same issue and this fixed it. Once changed run gradle clean && gradle build in your project root.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

adding the dpi to the drawable is invalid.  You should just be able to set it like so in the manifest:

```
<Application
  ...
  android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher" > 
  <!-- change ic_launcher to whatever your png is named -->
```

The typical folder structure is as follows:

```
/
  AndroidManifest.xml
  /res
    /drawable-ldpi
      ic_launcher.png       # 36x36
    /drawable-mdpi
      ic_launcher.png       # 48x48
    /drawable-hdpi
      ic_launcher.png       # 72x72
```

Once you've done this, you'll probably need to do a clean (eclipse -> project -> clean), but you'll know it was successful if a line like this appears in your `/gen/R.java` file:

```
public static final int ic_launcher = 0x...;
```

If it isn't, you can delete the R.java file and the ADT will immediately panic and rebuild it from scratch, incorporating your new drawables.

As a final note, sometimes the emulator seems to cling to the old icon - the clean should make it change, but if it doesn't, go into settings and uninstall the application and then run again from eclipse, everything should **REALLY** be clean (the same applies to actual devices as well)

**NOTE** the answer now includes the comments below

Answer (score 1):

make sure you have refreshed your Android project.  You might try changing the name of your icon files to "ic_launcher.png" which is the name used now.

Comment: Thanks.  However we are supposed to supply different image sizes for different resolution screens.  I'd like to avoid that solution and use the one properly supported.  Strange.

Comment: Also - how would I 'refresh' my Android project?  You mean run it again?

Comment: If you right click on your project in Package Explorer on the left you can choose Refresh and it should find any new files you've added or updated.

Comment: thanks! :)  its not showing the default icon, but its also not showing the icon i put in the folder haha.

Comment: Did you try changing the icon file name and removing the line from your manifest file?

Comment: Can you put your manifest file into your original question, I can't read it in the comment very well.  Also, it's not clear to me if you ever tried changing the names of your icon files from icon.png to ic_launcher.png -- your comments suggest that you didn't.