# Android Studio Manifest Missing Error In Gradle

Tags: android, gradle, actionbarsherlock, android-studio, android-manifest

I'm trying to figure out what I've done to my project. I recently added ActionBarSherlock to my project under the main `project/library/ActionBarSherlock`. When I did that something happened to my manifest file path because now the project cannot find it and I'm getting this error on Debug.

Gradle:

> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred configuring root project 'ToDoListProject'.

  > Failed to notify project evaluation listener.
  >   Main Manifest missing from C:\Users\Chris Johnson\AndroidStudioProjects\ToDoListProject\src\main\AndroidManifest.xml
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

The reason it can't find the manifest is because it's located in the file

```
C:\Users\Chris Johnson\AndroidStudioProjects\ToDoListProject\ToDoList\src\main\AndroidManifest.xml
```

How do I set it to the correct location again?

Thanks.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

In the `android` section of your `build.gradle` file, you can try adding `sourceSets` with the `manifest.srcFile` variable.

```
android {
  sourceSets {
      main {
          manifest.srcFile 'ToDoList/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml'
      }
  }
}
```

That path may need to be adjusted slightly.

Comment: Any idea what would've caused this in the first place? Either way I'll try this later on tonight, thanks.

Comment: It's hard to say what could cause this, since Android Studio is basically in alpha, a lot changes with each subsequent update, so these issues are hard to track down sometimes.

Comment: Originally had two "Gradle R package not found" and this error about AndroidManifest. I applied that to build.gradle and adjuste the path to mine. Now I have 50 "Gradle R package not found" instead of just two and I have only ONE project.

Comment: Why would anybody put their AndroidManifest.xml in /src/main?  This is not how traditional Android project guidelines recommend structuring a project.  This deviates from the norm.

Comment: Hence the phrase "That path may need to be adjusted slightly." As far as I recall, that's where Android Studio generates the manifest for a gradle project.

Comment: @IgorGanapolsky build flavours.

Comment: I also found out that if you give the same string as the project name and module name in Android Studio, this confuses gradle. I had a structure (of gradle modules) `MyModule/Mymodule` It tried to look for the sources in the outer one, but they were created in the inner

Comment: @Igor: it does not seem to 'deviate from the norm': http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide#TOC-Project-Structure

Comment: I stand corrected.  With the new Gradle build system, all projects are structured this way by default in Android Studio.

Answer (score 5):

You can do it from here **open module settings** -> **Select modules tab** -> **click on your module** -> **from structure tab on the right change path for manifest file**

you can find your manifest file inside [module name]/src/[sub directory]

Comment: For those of us who aren't familiar with android studio or android apps in general, where is this "open module settings"?

Answer (score 1):

I solved it by doing a clean via menu **Build -> Clean project** and a rebuild via menu **Build -> Rebuild project**

Comment: It solved mine too, and it was a modular project.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps not exactly for this question, however I have the same error message, and it was due to gradle project not configured (this happened after pull from git), I selected "accept theirs" for all conflicts. local.properties was missing.  So the team has removed files, "breaking" the project after the update.  I readded local.properties, then i was able to reset gradle to use the gradle wrapper.  Now it will recognize the android project including the manifest.