# Android Studio not found AndroidManifest.xml

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm using the Android Studio v0.2.x.

I just created a new application with default settings: **File**->**New Project**->**...**, then step by step.

When I built it, it failed. The log is:

> Android Source Generator: [MyApplication] AndroidManifest.xml file not found

But I have checked the source. It has the `AndroidManifest.xml` file. Any idea what causes this?

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by re-importing the project. By doing so, Android Studio will re-generate the .iml files.

Answer (score 0):

You can configure the location of the manifest file like this:

1. open the *Project Structure* dialog
2. go to "Modules" (in the left tree)
3. select "Android" in the middle column of the dialog
4. Now you see on the right side a list of files where you can pick the Manifest file.

Answer (score -6):

Try cleaning the project , after that refresh and try to build again.

```
Project -> Clean
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But I'm using the Android Studio. There is no menu "Project->Clean".

Comment: ah sorry, should've paid more attention.
have you tried this soulution?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17096983/android-studio-manifest-missing-error

Comment: Thanks. But it still failed.