# .android.support\appcompat-v7\23.1.1\AndroidManifest.xml (The system cannot find this file)

Tags: android

I am getting error and not able to build the gradle after i made changes in this following line,but i want 8.4.0 in my gradle

```
app.gradle
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.4.0'

project.gradle
dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.0.0-beta6'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:2.0.0-beta6'
```

Comment: Do you get  the same errors after removing it?

Comment: @ImAtWar didn't change it

Comment: So you het the errors after changing the following line, but you didnt make changes.

Comment: i was getting different error to updae gradle to 2.10 i did it now i am getting this error

Comment: Is this the build gradle? There is a separate file for you to edit. Using Android studio And perhaps using eclips you can change the plugins using `File > Project Structure `.

Comment: yes its build.gradle the problem is with gradle i know that

Comment: There isnt any error? In Android studio?

Comment: there is this error about manifest.xml not found

Comment: Can you try http://stackoverflow.com/a/33685639/2725502

Comment: Assumption, Play services 8.4.0 expects you to have manifest Android v23.1.1, but you are probably compiling/targeting a lower version so that manifest isn't generated.

Comment: @zgc7009 how should i change the version of Manifest ?

Comment: You can either bump your target API in your manifest/gradle to 23 or you can try downgrading your Google Play version.