# Missing Gradle Project Information. Please check if the IDE successfully synchronized its state with the Gradle Project Model

Tags: android

I found this error while exporting apk/sdk from android studio.
I dont know how to solve this.
please help.:

Missing Gradle Project Information. Please check if the IDE successfully synchronized its state with the Gradle Project Model.

thanks!!!

Comment: any chance that you have already tried the solutions that can be easly find by googling or you did not do any efforts?

Comment: yes i googled for it. but the problem is not solved yet.

Answer (score 29):

Just go to `menu` > `tools` > `Android` > `Sync Project with Gradle Files`. Hope this will work for you.
good luck

Comment: This advice may not work if you try to sign a project that already has been signed by another programmer and you don't have his key. So, in build.gradle you will have something like "storePassword KEYSTORE_PASSWORD" and it won't compile. In this case, I think, first you should define required variables and then compile.

Comment: @CoolMind How would I "define required variables" ? Could you expand on that?

Answer (score 22):

For those with the same problem, in android studio 3.1.4 it is just `file -> Sync Project with Gradle Files`

Answer (score 0):

Probably your project has been developed under another Gradle version. Try to read more about your problem here [Android Studio Manifest Missing Error In Gradle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17096983/android-studio-manifest-missing-error-in-gradle)

Comment: the game i have build in buildbox developer tool and all the code files i exported well. i also tried it with eclipse but application is getting crash and even when i export it in eclipse so it shows the error of src and gen but when i clean the project then both error gets clean but one new error appears called android dependency. I dont know why eclipse it deleting my bin file (android sdk.jar ) after cleaning.

Comment: even the game is running very cool in to buildbox application. please help me to get rid of this issue. I had to launch it before christmas and i am already late :(